# ESP8266 Using wifimanager with onSoftAPModeProbeRequestReceived

Tags: arduino, esp8266, wifimanager, arduino-esp8266

I would like to use https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager in conjunction with `onSoftAPModeProbeRequestReceived`. The end goal is to config the wifi with WifiMaager then "switch over" and send probe request information via the wifi.

I get this to work without wifi manager using the following

```
#include <ESP8266httpUpdate.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> 
#include <esp8266httpclient.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* ssid     = "someap";         // The SSID (name) of the Wi-Fi 
network you want to connect to
const char* password = "";     // The password of the Wi-Fi network
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;  
String macAddr = "";
WiFiEventHandler probeRequestPrintHandler; 
WiFiEventHandler probeRequestBlinkHandler;

bool blinkFlag;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    Serial.print("Starting");
    WiFi.persistent(false);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

    probeRequestPrintHandler =
    WiFi.onSoftAPModeProbeRequestReceived(&onProbeRequestPrint);
    probeRequestBlinkHandler =
    WiFi.onSoftAPModeProbeRequestReceived(&onProbeRequestBlink);

while ( status != 3) 
{
Serial.print("Attempting to connect to network, SSID: ");
Serial.println(ssid);
status = WiFi.status();
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
// wait 10 seconds for connection:
delay(10000);
}
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 
}

void onProbeRequestPrint(const WiFiEventSoftAPModeProbeRequestReceived& evt) 
{
if (macAddr != macToString(evt.mac))
{
macAddr = macToString(evt.mac);   
Serial.print("Probe request from: ");
Serial.print(macToString(evt.mac));
Serial.print(" RSSI: ");
Serial.println(evt.rssi);
}
}
void onProbeRequestBlink(const WiFiEventSoftAPModeProbeRequestReceived&) {
blinkFlag = true;
}
void loop() {
if (blinkFlag) {
HTTPClient http;  //Declare an object of class HTTPClient
http.begin("http://requestbin.fullcontact.com/110f1ss6a1?test=true");  
//Specify request destination
int httpCode = http.GET();     
Serial.println(httpCode);
if (httpCode > 0) { //Check the returning code
  String payload = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
  Serial.println(payload);                     //Print the response payload
}
http.end();   //Close connection
macAddr="";
blinkFlag = false;
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

status = 0;
}
delay(1000);
}
String macToString(const unsigned char* mac) {
char buf[20];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
       mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
return String(buf);
}
```

When the connection is established we rely on `WiFiEventHandler probeRequestPrintHandler;` and WiFiEventHandler probeRequestBlinkHandler; This does work and does collect the mac address, how ever it can not connect to the AP. Do I need to close the current wifi mode open the connection then close it?

Comment: goal of WiFiManager is to connect the esp8266 in STA mode to an AP. WiFiManager turns of SoftAP if esp8266 connects to AP in STA mode. The probe events are for AP mode. how does WiFiManager fit into this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems all I needed to do is add `WiFi.begin();` before `void loop()`